# What is the difference between make and makepkg?

Tags: arch-linux, make, makepkg

From [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PKGBUILD):

> Packages in Arch Linux are built using the `makepkg` utility. When makepkg is run, it searches for a `PKGBUILD` file in the current directory and follows the instructions therein to either compile or otherwise acquire the files to build a package archive (pkgname.pkg.tar.xz). The resulting package contains binary files and installation instructions, readily installable with pacman.

`Make` is a GNU utility that is used to build and install packages from source and to do so it searches for a makefile in the appropriate directory which feeds in the requiured inputs to `make`.

So `makepkg` is used to make pacman installable binaries and optionally `makepkg -si` can resolve dependencies(mainly used for AUR packages). Is the difference just in this dependency resolution and pacman specific stuff? It is just automation of stuff which could be manually done by `make` but on every distro.

Am I correct?
Sorry if this is a dumb question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## TL;DR

Advantages of `makepkg` over `make`:

- Abstracts the build system (`make`, `configure`, `cmake`, `qmake`, `npm`, `pybuild`, `ninja`, `pybuild`)
- Manages dependencies (build & runtime)
- Creates package which can be distributed or installed
- Allows distro-specific patches or configurations
- Supports installation/uninstallation/upgrade scripts
- Tracks files on system so you know why a specific file has been installed (who owns it)
- Makes uninstallation easier.
- Makes upgrades easier (renamed files in source package will not leave orphans, scripts can safely migrate databases).

---

## `--verbose`

`make` will execute a `MakeFile` in the current directory, building required targets.  `make install` will attempt to install those targets into `DESTDIR`.

`makepkg -i` builds based on the rules of `PKGBUILD`.  This could be:

```
configure
make
make install DESTDIR=/usr
```

or

```
cmake .
cmake --build . -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
ctest .
cmake --build . --target=install
```

or any of

```
cargo build --release
npm --build
pybuild
qmake
...
```

---

There are lots of build systems.  `make` is only one of them, and is often only a part of one (e.g. autoconf).  `PKGBUILD` is a nice way so that arch package users (or build machines) can use a single command (`makepkg`) without the need to know anything about the build system.  It's meant to define how to build a package instead of how to build the sources.

`PKGBUILD` also gives the opportunity to define build-dependencies or runtime dependencies.  This means if you need `cmake` to build a package, it will be automatically installed (if `-s` is specified) and automatically removed (if `-r` is specified). If your package depends on `python3`, then it will ensure that `python3` is installed on your system automatically.

`PKGBUILD` also gives the possibility for Arch maintainers to add their own patches/customizations to original source packages.  If a upstream package installs a library executable to `/usr/lib/`, but Arch's standards would rather have these in `/usr/libexec/`, then the `PKGBUILD` file allows these kind of customizations.

---

If you don't use the `-i` option, `makepkg` does not try to install the build.  Instead the output is a `.tar.xz` file which could be uploaded to an archive and installed by other users with `pacman`.  This is how the official arch repositories work.

Arch developers will write `PKGBUILD` files, then build machines will parse those files, build packages, and upload them to the official repository so that you can use `pacman` to download/install them.

---

Another advantage of using `makepkg` over `make install` is that your package manager keeps an index of what is installed, where, and which version.  This means if you ever have a question about why a file is on your system, you should be able to query the package manager who will tell you which package "owns" the file and which version it is.  When you uninstall the package, the package manager knows of all files so that it doesn't leave anything orphaned.  When you upgrade your package, the package manager knows which files to replace/rename/delete during the installation and may also run a script or two to ensure that things migrate smoothly.

---